# How to increase the line number section width in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, text-editor, emacs24

Emacs shows the line numbers properly with default font size, however when I increase the font size, it breaks out. Is there any variable to adjust this width?

[image]

Comment: That is clearly a bug (I can reproduce it with emacs 24.3)... I suggest it to report it (M-x report-emacs-bug)